# How can crontab print messages in console?

Tags: linux, printf, scheduling, cron

Hi I am really new in Linux:D

I made a crontab program which is supposed to print current time in console every 3 minutes.

What I did is below.

1. I made a crontab. In terminal, command
   "`crontab -e`" and add a phrase "`*/3 * * * * /home/user/a.out`"
2. a.out is a result file of "`gcc WowCron.c`".

Code is below.

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
  time_t now;
  time(&now);
  printf("this is what we call cron does: %s\n", ctime(&now));
  return 0;
}
```

and it works wonderfully when run individually.

1. Then I ran a "`service cron restart`" command in terminal. 
   Now when I command "`crontab -l`", I can see the messages what I wrote in crontab.
2. The problem is somehow I think it works, but never prints time message.

Q. How can I make this print time every 3 minutes?

Comment: what's wrong with my writing? My C code totally crashed!!! anyway that code is nothing special, but print current time.

Comment: There is no need to restart `cron`. It reads all the crontabs each time it runs, so that any user can update theirs at any time and see the results immediately.

Comment: @tripleee So what is the purpose of service cron restart command means? Was it just an useless action? Anyway, Thanks for answering consistently.

Answer (score 1):

The standard output from a `cron` job does not end up on the console. Try using the [`syslog`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/syslog) facility.

Alternatively, if you don't need to integrate this into a larger C program of your own, use the [`logger`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?logger+1) command.

```
*/3 * * * * logger Still here ...
```

(The system log already includes a time stamp.)

Any standard output and standard error from a cron job ends up being sent by email to the job owner. Maybe you should examine your mailbox, or maybe your email is not working properly?

Answer (score 1):

Cron triggers a new process to start in the background. You configure it through a terminal (which is a process) but it has nothing to do with that terminal otherwise. Each process has it's own STDOUT, STDIN, STDERR so as the cron tasks is on a new process it won't print to your terminal process' STDOUT

As tripleee says if you'd like it to print syslog is a good place to go, or you can make it append to a file of your choice.

If you just want the program to run at a time interval in a terminal then a Shell Script is probably a better option:

```
while : 
do
    date
    sleep 180 
done
```

Or you can replace the "date" function with "./a.out" and run it from the same directory