# crontab script not working

Tags: unix, cron

I have created unix simple script that shows "Hello Word". Script name is cron.sh

In crontab I wrote   `46 8 * * * /home/training/My_Local/cron.sh`

But I am not getting output on screen. Am I doing any mistake?

Comment: Cron does not send output to screen by default. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390221/how-can-crontab-print-messages-in-console for other techniques to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the cron output is sent to the user's mail. The cron job does not have a "screen" to display to. In order to see your results, I would recommend redirecting stdout and stderr to a log file.

```
    46 8 * * * /home/training/My_Local/cron.sh > /home/training/My_Local/cron.log
```

Comment: Dear Rusan,Kaushik Thank you! now I understood how it works.Thank you for your guidance.